# Problem at getting the memberCount of every guilds + excepting the bots in the guilds (Discord.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Making a bot in Discord.js, and i wanna see how many **users** the are in the servers that the bot is in(excepting the bots of the servers)

I've been trying for weeks but when i wanna get the value, it gives me something else..

Here's my code:

```
var AllUsers = 0
client.on('ready', () => {
    client.guilds.cache.forEach( guild => {
        var memners = 0
        mems = mems + guild.memberCount
        var Bcount = 0
        Bcount = Bcount + guild.members.cache.filter(member => !member.user.bot).size
        var users = mems - Bcount
        AllUsers = AllUsers + users
    })
    console.log(`the bot is ready and dealing with ${AllUsers} users`)
}
```

In this code i'm actually excepting the count of the bots from the memberCount itself, but my problem is that it just doesn't work! the code `guild.members.cache.filter(*member* => !member.user.bot).size` doesn't work! it doesn't give me an error..

It actually gives me this(i made some console.logs for that):

```
in my Bots server: 
members: 5    
Bcount: 1  
users: 4   
AllUsers: 4
---------  
in Code server:      
members: 4    
Bcount: 1  
users: 3   
AllUsers: 7
---------  
in Games server:  
members: 3    
Bcount: 1
users: 2
AllUsers: 9
---------
```

Its like the value of the Bcount is "`1`" while it's not!

I've tried the: guild.members.cache.filter(*member* => **member.user.bot**).size instead of: `guild.members.cache.filter(member => !member.user.bot).size` and this time the value of the Bcount was "`0`".

It's really ridiculous! cause all those three servers have **2** bots in it but it gave me **1** and **0**!

Please if you know how to solve this problem help me.

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue here is that you're only using the users from the member cache, which is not guaranteed to contain all users in a server. You will need to fetch the users (request them from the API) instead of using the cache.

Here is code taken directly from the Discord.js guide [here](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/faq.html#how-do-i-find-all-online-members-of-a-guild):

```js
// First use guild.members.fetch to make sure all members are cached
guild.members.fetch({ withPresences: true }).then(fetchedMembers => {
    const totalOnline = fetchedMembers.filter(member => member.presence?.status === 'online');
    // Now you have a collection with all online member objects in the totalOnline variable
    console.log(`There are currently ${totalOnline.size} members online in this guild!`);
});
```

However, you can't fetch members if your bot doesn't have the `GUILD_MEMBERS` intent along with this same thing being enabled in your discord application page (explained in the above link). Here is the [official guide page for intents](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html#privileged-intents) for reference.

We can adapt the above code to your specific purposes with the below code:

```js
let AllUsers = 0;
// async is added here so we can use await in the function
client.on('ready', async () => {
    const guilds = client.guilds.cache;
    // Loop through all guilds
    for (let [guildId, guild] of guilds) {
        // Wait for the members to be fetched, then add to AllUsers
        const members = await guild.members?.fetch();
        // If members is defined, then add the count
        AllUsers += (members !== undefined) ? members?.filter(member => !member.user.bot).size : 0;
    }

    console.log(`the bot is ready and dealing with ${AllUsers} users`);
}
```

*Note: Do **not** use `var` unless you have a very specific reason. [Here is a decent explaination](https://chris-franklin.com/why-is-var-considered-a-bad-practice-in-javascript/)*

The above code isn't very efficient (nor does it handle potential errors), it could be rewritten to fetch all members of all guilds at the same time using [Promise.all();](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) but considering that this code only runs on startup right now, it's best not to send all of those requests to the API at once.

Do be considerate with this code though, you shouldn't be fetching all members often. In fact, Discord.js v12 used to have a `.fetchAllMembers()` function, but [this was removed](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v13.html#clientoptions-fetchallmembers) due to going against the intentions of data scraping users.